# Need to do a barplot with large number of xlab values. How do I make them fit?

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

This is the code that I have input:

```
CountriesChart = data.frame(NamesofC =
  factor(c(Countries),
levels = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'lvoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Northern Mariana Islands", "North Korea", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Phillipines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Romana", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas", "The Gambia", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands, US.", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")),
Values = c(OneData$exp_mean))
barplot(CountriesChart$Values, names = c(CountriesChart$levels))
```

I need to make this into a graph that shows the countries' names, but it won't show up because there are so many of them. What can I do to fix this? This is the end result of the graph with this code:

[image]

Comment: With so many items, it will be hard to have them displayed all. One option would be to rotate the plot or perhaps split the graph into several figures.

Comment: How would I rotate the plot?

Comment: Frankly, I would just use `ggplot2`. http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_flip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
barplot(CountriesChart$Values, names = c(CountriesChart$levels), las=2)
```